# How to write a directory with a file in golang?

Tags: go

Right now, I am trying to use os.Create but it gives me an error while specifying the path of the file. I have to upload my file from HTML to my file system in a specific directory.

```
file,err:= c.FormFile("file")
if err!=nil{
    checkErr(err)
}
src, err := file.Open()
if err!=nil{
    checkErr(err)
}
defer src.Close()

abs,err :=filepath.Abs("/dir1/dir2/")
if err!=nil{
    checkErr(err)
}

dst,err := os.Create(abs+"/"+file.Filename)
if err !=nil{
    checkErr(err)
}
defer dst.Close()
if _,err = io.Copy(dst,src); err!=nil{
    checkErr(err)
}
```

I have to upload the file to dir2. Please help me out. Thank you.

Comment: Provide the code, please

Comment: Please see the code @Rudziankoŭ

Comment: if `abs` is `/dir1/dir2/` than you concatenate extra `/` when creating file with `os.Create`

Comment: This may not be the problem, but replace `abs+"/"+file.Filename` with `filepath.Join(abs, file.Filename)`.  Separately, using a client supplied filename like this is dangerous.

Comment: Any errors does the program give?

Comment: Yes!! Never knew we cannot join the strings that way in Go. You have to use strings.Join().
I simply solved this problem using, os.Create(strings.Join([]string{path,file.FileName},"/")) where my path is simply a string of my directory path.

Answer (score 11):

Use [filepath.Join](https://godoc.org/path/filepath#Join) to create the path from the directory `dir` and the file name.

To protect against a write to an arbitrary location in the file system, clean the path with [filepath.Base](https://godoc.org/path/filepath#Base).

```
file, err := c.FormFile("file")
if err != nil {
    checkErr(err)
    return
}
src, err := file.Open()
if err != nil {
    checkErr(err)
    return
}
defer src.Close()

dst, err := os.Create(filepath.Join(dir, filepath.Base(file.Filename))) // dir is directory where you want to save file.
if err != nil {
    checkErr(err)
    return
}
defer dst.Close()
if _, err = io.Copy(dst, src); err != nil {
    checkErr(err)
    return
}
```

Comment: It's not obvious what is ```checkErr(err)``` I have no such function in the scope and quick googling don't get the answer. Is it just "some user defined function" which checks error?

Comment: @standalone The function `checkErr` comes from the question. It's an application supplied function for handling the error. There are other ways to handle errors than as is done in the question and this answer, but that's outside the scope of what was asked.

Answer (score 0):

That is how I did it without using io.Copy(...)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
)

func main() {
    cwd, _ := os.Getwd()
    err := os.Mkdir("new-dir", os.ModePerm) // you might want different file access, this suffice for this example
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("Created %s at %s\n", "new-dir", cwd)
    }

    path := filepath.Join(cwd, "new-dir", "test-file.txt")
    newFilePath := filepath.FromSlash(path)
    file, err := os.Create(newFilePath)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()
    fmt.Printf("File created successfully at %s\n", newFilePath)
}
```